# NoSuchElementException: Unable to select dropdown item

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, automation, scripting

I'm unable to select the dropdown.
The code for the dropdown is

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="navigatorTable">
    <td nowrap="" align="left">
    <span class="dropdownbutton showSingle bound">
        <a><img class="vAlignSub" src="/images/add.gif">&nbsp;Create Account&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="../../images/actionitems_collapse.gif"></a>&nbsp;
    </span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And in python I have the following code.

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='dropdownbutton show fork']")).click()
select.select_by_value('1')
```

But I'm getting

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: 
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath",
"selector":"//span[@class='dropdownbutton showSingle bound']"}
```

Please help me with the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `Select` in this case as though the class name says it's a drop down but it's span not an `select` html node. So, you can't use `Select` approach here.

You have to make sure the script waits until the span element is loaded.

```
#Imports required
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as E
```

Now get the element and click on it (check the xpath)

```
ele = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='dropdownbutton showSingle bound']//img")))
ele.click()
```

Comment: Thanks a billion, supputuri. Thanks Thanks Thanks

Comment: [Upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers